Save tensorflow model without any input
I am trying to benchmark matmul operation and save the operation as a model in .pb format.
class GEMMBenchmark(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, m, n, k):
        super(GEMMBenchmark, self).__init__()
        self.A = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal((m, k)), trainable=False)
        self.B = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal((k, n)), trainable=False)

    def __call__(self):
        return tf.matmul(self.A, self.B)

GEMM = GEMMBenchmark(1, 1, 1)
GEMM.save("GEMM")

I get this error when I try to save the model which does not required any inputs. Seems like the forward pass is not defined.

Any workaround or alternative implementations?
Thanks!

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

I am not sure what you are really trying to achieve, your model is too incomplete to be saved. This is one way you can add some extra to make the save function work:
class GEMMBenchmark(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, m, n, k):
        super(GEMMBenchmark, self).__init__()
        self.A = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal((m, k)), trainable=False)
        self.B = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal((k, n)), trainable=False)

    def call(self, inputs=None):
        return tf.matmul(self.A, self.B)

GEMM = GEMMBenchmark(1, 1, 1)
GEMM.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError())
GEMM.fit([1], [1])
GEMM.save("GEMM")


I am trying to run one single matrix multiplication operation on various GPU to determine latency and energy consumption. Your code work like a charm. Thanks!
